# django to translate items from a enum into other languages

Tags: python, django, enums

I have many variables in a enum, which is for a system log, but I don't want make the messages translated into other lauguages in the system log. However, I have a page to display those variables I want to make them translated(like english to chinese).

How to make those in single quote translated.

```
# enumeration implement method
def enum(*sequential, **named):
    enums = dict(zip(sequential, range(len(sequential))), **named)
    reverse = dict((value, key) for key, value in enums.iteritems())
    sequence = dict((key, value) for key, value in enums.iteritems())
    enums['reverse_mapping'] = reverse
    enums['sequence_mapping'] = sequence
    return type('Enum', (), enums)

TASKS = enum(
    CREATE_NETWORK='Create Network', # <- Can't be translated here
    UPDATE_NETWORK='Update Network',
    ... ....
    DELETE_USER='Delete User')
```

Comment: what Enum implementation are you using?

Comment: @fixmycode already update with my enum implementation.

Comment: When you say "translated" you mean into a non-English language?  Also, have you checked out [`enum34`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) which is a backport of the new Enum data type in Python 3.4?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [`enum34`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) backport, something like this might work:

```
class Tasks(Enum):
    CREATE_NETWORK = 'Create Network'
    UPDATE_NETWORK = 'Update Network'
    # ...
    def translate(self):
        return some_translation_lib.translate(self.value)
```

The method names I'm sure need to be corrected, but hopefully that gives you an idea.

Also, check out [this answer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) for other Django/Enum tips.